# Есть ли у Андроид такой виджет(см. скриншот)?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile-development, мобильная-разработка

[image: пример нужной вьюхи]

Всем привет! Мне нужно сделать вьюху, как на фото в ссылке. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли такой виджет у Андроид или где-то описывается нечто похожее? Заранее спасибо).

Comment: вы можете сделать "полоски" на основе ProgressBar'а и базовых знаний математики)

Answer (score 4):

Да все верно, можно сделать такой обьект например

```
package com.example.testapp;

public class RateBlank {
    public RateBlank(Integer _rate1, Integer _rate2, Integer _rate3, Integer _rate4, Integer _rate5) {
        rate1 = _rate1;
        rate2 = _rate2;
        rate3 = _rate3;
        rate4 = _rate4;
        rate5 = _rate5;
        calcSumma();
    }

    public Integer getRate5() {
        return (int) (100 * rate5 / getSumma());
    }

    public void setRate5(Integer rate5) {
        if (rate5 > 0) {
            calcSumma();
            this.rate5 = rate5;
        }
    }

    public Integer getRate4() {
        return (int) (100 * rate4 / getSumma());
    }

    public void setRate4(Integer rate4) {
        if (rate4 > 0) {
            calcSumma();
            this.rate4 = rate4;
        }
    }

    public Integer getRate3() {
        return (int) (100 * rate3 / getSumma());
    }

    public void setRate3(Integer rate3) {
        if (rate3 > 0) {
            calcSumma();
            this.rate3 = rate3;
        }
    }

    public Integer getRate2() {
        return (int) (100 * rate2 / getSumma());
    }

    public void setRate2(Integer rate2) {
        if (rate2 > 0) {
            calcSumma();
            this.rate2 = rate2;
        }
    }

    public Integer getRate1() {
        return (int) (100 * rate1 / getSumma());
    }

    public void setRate1(Integer rate1) {
        if (rate1 > 0) {
            calcSumma();
            this.rate1 = rate1;
        }
    }

    public Double getAverageRate() {
        calcAverageRate();
        return averageRate;
    }

    public void calcSumma() {
        summa = rate1 + rate2 + rate3 + rate4 + rate5;
    }

    public void calcAverageRate() {
        averageRate = (rate1 + 2 * rate2 + 3 * rate3 + 4 * rate4 + 5. * rate5) / getSumma();
    }

    Integer summa = 1;
    Integer rate5 = 0;
    Integer rate4 = 0;
    Integer rate3 = 0;
    Integer rate2 = 0;
    Integer rate1 = 0;
    Double averageRate = 0.0;

    public Integer getSumma() {
        return summa;
    }

}
```

И создав фрагмент для использования по месту

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Locale;

public class RateBlankFragment extends Fragment {

    private RateBlank rate;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rate_blank_fragment, container, false);

        rate = new RateBlank(100,100,400,500,500);
        setViews(view);

        return view;
    }

    ProgressBar pbRate5,pbRate4,pbRate3,pbRate2,pbRate1;
    TextView txvAverageRate;

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void setViews(View view) {
        // получить ссылки на элементы интерфейса

        pbRate5 = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pbRate5);
        pbRate4 = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pbRate4);
        pbRate3 = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pbRate3);
        pbRate2 = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pbRate2);
        pbRate1 = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pbRate1);
        txvAverageRate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txvAverageRate);

        pbRate5.setProgress(this.rate.getRate5());
        pbRate4.setProgress(this.rate.getRate4());
        pbRate3.setProgress(this.rate.getRate3());
        pbRate2.setProgress(this.rate.getRate2());
        pbRate1.setProgress(this.rate.getRate1());
        txvAverageRate.setText(String.format(Locale.UK, "%.1f", this.rate.getAverageRate()));
    }
}
```

И конечно разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".RateBlankFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txvAverageRate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="0,0"
        android:textSize="90dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgStarRate1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txvRate5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgStarRate5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txvAverageRate"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgStarRate5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txvRate4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgStarRate4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txvAverageRate"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgStarRate4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txvRate3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgStarRate3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txvAverageRate"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgStarRate3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txvRate2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgStarRate2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txvAverageRate"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgStarRate2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txvRate1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgStarRate1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txvAverageRate"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgStarRate1" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbRate5"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="25dp"
        android:min="0"
        android:max="100"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgStarRate5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgStarRate5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgStarRate5" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbRate4"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="25dp"
        android:min="0"
        android:max="100"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgStarRate4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgStarRate4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgStarRate4" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbRate3"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="25dp"
        android:min="0"
        android:max="100"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgStarRate3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgStarRate3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgStarRate3" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbRate2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="25dp"
        android:min="0"
        android:max="100"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgStarRate2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgStarRate2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgStarRate2" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbRate1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="25dp"
        android:min="0"
        android:max="100"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgStarRate1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgStarRate1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgStarRate1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgStarRate5"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txvRate5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgStarRate4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txvRate4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgStarRate5" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgStarRate3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txvRate3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgStarRate4" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgStarRate2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txvRate2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgStarRate3" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgStarRate1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txvRate1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgStarRate2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Немного доработав стили и получиш нужный результат

Использовать так например

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/frCombo"
    android:name="com.example.testapp.RateBlankFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout="@layout/rate_blank_fragment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/llBlock"/>
```

Результат такой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Это мне здорово помогло!)